# Microsoft PowerApps - unable to add a New table from external data

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I have been trying for a while to add an on-premises table to the dataverse for a model driven app.

I've got the on premises gateway and SQL server connector working fine in the same environment, returning data to a canvas app. However no matter what I try using this same gateway and connector I can't add a table for a model driven app:

[image]